Next.js with Clerk: "ClerkJS: Something went wrong initializing Clerk" error
I'm building a Next.js application using Clerk for authentication, and I'm encountering the following error in the console:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: ClerkJS: Something went wrong initializing Clerk.
    at s (clerk.browser.js:2:41560)
    at Ge.<anonymous> (clerk.browser.js:2:206055)
    at async Ge.load (clerk.browser.js:2:184013)
    at async _IsomorphicClerk.loadClerkJS (index.mjs:1496:9)

This error occurs when the page loads, preventing Clerk from initializing properly.
My middleware.ts file looks like this:
import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const isPublicRoute = createRouteMatcher(["/", "/login", "/register", "/api/webhook"]);
const isAdminRoute = createRouteMatcher(["/admin(.*)"]);
const isProfessionalRoute = createRouteMatcher(["/professional(.*)"]);

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, req) => {
  const { userId, has } = auth();

  // Allow public routes
  if (isPublicRoute(req)) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  // Redirect to sign in for protected routes if not authenticated
  if (!userId) {
    return auth().redirectToSignIn({ returnBackUrl: req.url });
  }

  // Protect admin routes
  if (isAdminRoute(req)) {
    if (!has({ role: "admin" })) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', req.url));
    }
  }

  // Protect professional routes
  if (isProfessionalRoute(req)) {
    if (!has({ role: "professional" })) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', req.url));
    }
  }

  // For all other routes, allow access
  return NextResponse.next();
});

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!_next|[^?]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)',
    '/(api|trpc)(.*)',
  ],
};

And my app/layout.tsx:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import {
  ClerkProvider,
  SignInButton,
  SignedIn,
  SignedOut,
  UserButton,
} from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <header>
            <SignedOut>
              <SignInButton />
            </SignedOut>
            <SignedIn>
              <UserButton />
            </SignedIn>
          </header>
          {children}
        </body>
      </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}

I've checked my environment variables and Clerk dashboard settings, but I'm still unable to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Verifying environment variables

Simplifying the middleware

